# Copy the XML with additional logic using XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I want to copy the whole xml and apply this additional logic:
If /OrderMessage/IncomingOrderMessage/IncomingOrder/TransferDetails/TransferDetails_item(just check for the first one)/quantity tag exists
then set  /OrderMessage/IncomingOrderMessage/IncomingOrder/doNotTransfer to true.
Otherwise just copy /OrderMessage/IncomingOrderMessage/IncomingOrder/doNotTransfer as it is.

Input.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OrderMessage>
   <IncomingOrderMessage>
     <IncomingOrder>
        <totalOrderQuantity>10000</totalOrderQuantity>
        <totalOrderPrice>500000</totalOrderPrice>
        <TransferDetails>       
           <TransferDetails_item>
              <quantity>5000</quantity>
              <price>250000</price>
             <location>India</location>
           </TransferDetails_item>
           <TransferDetails_item>
              <quantity>5000</quantity>
              <price>250000</price>
              <location>US</location>
          </TransferDetails_item>
       </TransferDetails>
      <orderCurrency>USD</orderCurrency>
      <doNotTransfer>false</doNotTransfer>
      <orderPayment>Credit</orderPayment>
   </IncomingOrder>
 </IncomingOrderMessage>
</OrderMessage>
```

Output.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <OrderMessage>
    <IncomingOrderMessage>
       <IncomingOrder>
           <totalOrderQuantity>10000</totalOrderQuantity>
           <totalOrderPrice>500000</totalOrderPrice>
           <TransferDetails>        
                <TransferDetails_item>
                   <quantity>5000</quantity>
                   <price>250000</price>
                   <location>India</location>
                </TransferDetails_item>
                <TransferDetails_item>
                   <quantity>5000</quantity>
                   <price>250000</price>
                   <location>US</location>
                </TransferDetails_item>
          </TransferDetails>
          <orderCurrency>USD</orderCurrency>
          <doNotTransfer>true</doNotTransfer>
          <orderPayment>Credit</orderPayment>
      </IncomingOrder>
   </IncomingOrderMessage>
</OrderMessage>
```

Could someone please help me on it.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the XSLT stylesheet you have so far and describe how it is not working. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or shortly:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="doNotTransfer[../TransferDetails/TransferDetails_item/quantity]">
    <xsl:copy>true</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If the value of `doNotTransfer` is always `true` or `false`, you could make the 2nd template:

```
<xsl:template match="doNotTransfer">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="boolean(../TransferDetails/TransferDetails_item/quantity)" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am able to get the output with the below xslt:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="no"/>
       <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
         <xsl:copy>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
         </xsl:copy>
       </xsl:template>

       <xsl:template match="IncomingOrder">
         <xsl:choose>
           <xsl:when test="//TransferDetails_item[1]/quantity ">
             <xsl:copy>
                 <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node() except doNotTransfer"/>
                 <doNotTransfer>true</doNotTransfer>
             </xsl:copy>

          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
               <xsl:copy>
                 <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
               </xsl:copy>
          </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
   </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Your question is tagged `xslt-1.0` and your stylesheet declares `version="1.0"` - but the `except` operator  will only work if the processor supports XSLT 2.0.